# An association not permitted in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, associations, primary-key

i have an Sql server database in which i have three tables:

**Affaire** : the primary key ( `id_affaire`) and a foreign Key ( `id_resp`) references to the table Users and another foreign key (`id_project`) references to the table Project

**Project** : with `id_project` as a primary key and `id_chef` foreign key references to the table Users

**Users** : `id_user` is a primary key

[image: demo]

the problem is that Sql Server blocked the circled  association :

```
'Project' table saved successfully
'AFFAIRE' table
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_AFFAIRE_Project'.  
L'instruction ALTER TABLE est en conflit avec la contrainte FOREIGN KEY "FK_AFFAIRE_Project". Le conflit s'est produit dans la base de données "PLUS", table "dbo.Project", column 'id_project'.
```

What is the reason of this error? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that there is at least one record in `Affaire` with a `id_project` which doesn't exist in table `Project`.

You fix this by either deleting or updating the offending `Affaire` records, or by inserting the missing `Project` record

Answer (score 1):

Run the following in Enterprise Manager

```
Select * from Affaire a
Where Not exists 
   (Select * From Project
    Where id_project = a.id_project)
```

This will show you, that the Affair table has rows in it that violate the FK constraint you are trying to create.  You have to modify or delete these rows before you can create the constraint.